# JavaFX ImageView: Can I retrieve the scaled image size when preserveRatio = true?

Tags: java, imageview, javafx, scale

In my application I use an ImageView to display an image. I don't want the image to be distorted, so I call [setPreserveRatio(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setPreserveRatio%28boolean%29). As described in the documentation, height and width "may be scaled to get the best fit in a width by height rectangle while preserving the original aspect ratio". Is there a possibility to retrieve the scaled image height and width? The problem is, I do not know what is regarded as the "best fit".

Comment: I believe you can retrieve the scaled image's bounds via imageView.getBoundsInParent() which considers all local transformations.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem fortunately enough you can get the bounds of the displayed image and calculate the ratio like so:

```
@FXML
ImageView imageView;
double getScaleXRatio()
{ 
    return imageView.getBoundsInParent().getWidth()/imageView.getImage().getWidth();
}

double getScaleYRatio()
{ 
    return imageView.getBoundsInParent().getHeight()/imageView.getImage().getHeight();
}
```